# Python regex: search for HTML tags and modify them

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I got an HTML file as string and want to change all `<img src="http:.../../filename.png ..>` to `<img src="id:filename.png>` How can I do this with regex?

I got this so far:

```
urls = re.findall(r'src=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', html)
allUrls = ', '.join(urls)
```

Comment: Don't ever parse HTML with regex. Use HTML parsers like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`.

Comment: @alecxe: There *are* applications for regular expressions in combination with HTML. **Usually** a HTML parser is the better solution, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure, thanks, `ever` was to add some emphasis.

Comment: Theoretically HTML/XML/Java cannot be parsed using regular expressions. One needs to use a context free grammar for this.

Comment: thanks for your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579133/python-replace-src-of-all-img-elements-using-parser seems to solve my problem using HTML parsers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the HTML, then regular expressions are fine.

Python:

```py
import re
html = re.sub(r'(<img src=").+/(.+">)', r'\1id:\2', html)
```

HTML:

```html
<img src="http://example.com/filename1.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/filename2.jpg">
```

Otherwise, a regular expression would get extremely messy.  I suggest [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html).  [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is also great.

```py
import lxml.etree, os, urlparse
root = lxml.etree.HTML(html)
for img in root.iter("img"):
    src = img.get("src", None)
    if src is not None:
        if urlparse.urlparse(src).scheme in ("http", "https"):
            src_path = urlparse.urlparse(src).path
            src_path_base = os.path.basename(src)
            src = "id:" + os.path.basename(src)
            img.set("src", src)
html = lxml.etree.tostring(root)
```

This copes with many cases that would be awkward if not impossible with regular expressions. Examples:

```html
<img src=http://example.com/filename.jpg>

<img src=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffilename.jpg>

<img title="src=http://example.com/bait.jpg" src=http://example.com/filename.jpg>

<img src=data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==>

<img
src
= 
http://example.com/filename.jpg
>

<img src="http://example.com/book report cover.jpg"> <!-- invalid but common -->
```