# Saving Images from URL

Tags: python, regex, directory, download

I'm trying to create a script that will download and save all image files from a website into a directory. This is my code but I can't get it to download the files and save them, can anyone see why not? I know there's another way it can be done using BeautifulSoup/Soup but I'm trying to get learn about regex and what can be done with it. Can anyone help?

```
import traceback
import sys, re
from time import sleep
from urllib import urlretrieve

images = re.findall(r'([-\w]+\.(?:jpg))', webpage.read())
try:

    filename='./dogg/file.html'
    urlretrieve('http://dogpicturesite.com/', filename)
    webpage=open(filename, 'r')
    print "Downloading Images....."
    time.sleep(5)
    print "Images Downloaded."
    print images

except:
    print "Failed to Download Images"
    raw_input('Press Enter to exit...')
    sys.exit()
```

From this script I can list the .jpg files on the webpage, what I now want to do is download them but from here I'm unsure how to download them. I thought it would be easier with the above script but would it be easier to edit the one below?

```
import sys, urllib, re
    def imagefiles(webpage):
        print ' imagefiles()'
        images = re.findall(r'([-\w]+\.(?:jpg))', webpage)

        for image in images:
            print image

    def main():
        sys.argv.append('http://dogpicturesite.com/')
        if len(sys.argv) != 2:
            print '[-] Image Files'
            return
        page = webpage.webpage(sys.argv[1])
        imagefiles(webpage)
```

Comment: why not wget or curl?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Perhaps you should try printing the specific exception you are `except`ing.

Comment: the 'except:' will catch all exceptions and make debugging more difficult.  Try it without try/except and see what exception you're getting.

Comment: I would recommend learning BeautifulSoup too,  as a DOM parser is in general  much better way to deal with HTML than regex.

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems here:

1. You never defined `webpage` but you try to use it here:

   ```
   images = re.findall(r'([-\w]+\.(?:jpg))', webpage)
   ```

   You need to define `webpage` before this line.
2. You imported `urlretrieve` directly using:

   ```
   from urllib import urlretrieve
   ```

   Thus, you need to remove the `urllib.` part of this line:

   ```
   urllib.urlretrieve('http://dogpicturesite.com/', 'C:/images')
   ```
3. You never imported `re` or `time`, but you use them in the code.

Note however that all of these bugs, each of which would have raised a `NameError`, are covered/silenced by the `try/except` block.

Answer (score 0):

You used the statement

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
```

but then refer to urllib.urlretrieve.

The line

```
 urllib.urlretrieve('http://dogpicturesite.com/', 'C:/images')
```

was triggering a NameError, but since you were using a catchall bare exception line

```
except:
```

it was hiding that error. When I remove the plain `except:` I saw

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dog.py", line 8, in
>   
>       urllib.urlretrieve('http://dogpicturesite.com/', 'C:/images') NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

That line would be

```
     urlretrieve('http://dogpicturesite.com/', 'C:/images')
```

to not trigger a name error.

A good rule for Python is to only catch the exceptions you are expecting, like

except IOError:

since an IOError might occur during the file write process. However, a NameError should only occur due to a programming error and you wouldn't want to hide or handle that in the same way.

Next, urllib.urlretrieve does not take a directory as an argument - it needs a filename. Otherwise, it will tell you

> IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: './dogg'

Next, so now that we know urlretrieve saves to a file... we have to open the file. Change the first part to

```
filename='./dogg/file.html'
urlretrieve('http://dogpicturesite.com/', filename)
webpage=open(filename, 'r')
```

now executing that brings us to the next exception that was being hidden: The `re` module has not been imported, so 
        images = re.findall(r'([-\w]+.(?:jpg))', webpage)

was triggering a NameError.

add 
    `import re`

to the top.

Then, the next line would be

```
images = re.findall(r'([-\w]+\.(?:jpg))', webpage.read())
```

However we also didn't import `time` earlier, so we get a name error.
Add

```
from time import sleep
```

to the top and change that line to
    sleep(5)

And now the program runs without errors.

However! Note that it doesn't actually download any of the images, since it's not doing anything with the images variable. At least add a

```
print images
```

and you can see how the regex is working. I got

```
jal@squiddle:~$ python dog.py 
['instrument-dog-184x184.jpg', 'instrument-dog.jpg', 'wallpaper-christmas-chihuahua-135x80.jpg', 'more-135x80.jpg', 'instrument-dog-184x184.jpg', 'more-184x184.jpg', 'eye-covered-184x184.jpg', 'cute-puppy-184x184.jpg', 'hello-dog-184x184.jpg', 'bathing-dog-184x184.jpg', 'screaming-dog-184x184.jpg', 'patches-and-dylan-184x184.jpg', 'cast-dog-184x184.jpg', 'screaming-puppy-184x184.jpg', 'miserable-dog-184x184.jpg', 'sun-dog-184x184.jpg', 'sleeping-dog-184x184.jpg', '291638_10150913381017747_226545279_o-184x184.jpg', 'swimming-dogs-184x184.jpg', 'chores-dog-184x184.jpg', 'IMG_20120701_0354361-184x184.jpg', 'close-up-dog1-184x184.jpg', 'let-the-dog-in-184x184.jpg', 'baths-184x184.jpg']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your indepth answer. I've updated my code with your changes but I still can't get it to work. Did i put the changes in the right place?

Comment: @milly if you mean the code as posted now, you need to remove the 'except:'. That catches all exceptions and is hiding your error. As posted currently, you have an indentation error in the try block.

Comment: Also, it's still only retrieving the image names... You'd need to add more code to download them after you get the images list.

Comment: I can already get the image list via another script, it's the downloading part that I'm having the issue with.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I'm using to print the names if the .jpg files, now I need to find how to download them.

Comment: @milly you could do that with the same urllib.urlretrieve method, in a loop over the images List.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen pyparsing? It'll definately scrape off all the image links for you in a jiffy and return the links to you to download.

If you go through the [examples](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples) set out here then you would be able to alter it to taste. Also check out this link [Replace SRC of all IMG elements using Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579133/python-replace-src-of-all-img-elements-using-parser)